# Mysql fetch data selection from html checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to get multiple return value for checkbox. But problem is with following code check box only can echo a single value. Even I select multiple checkbox I am getting only single value form it. How to solve it

```
$q2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT product_img_url FROM temp_img");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q2)) {
    $product_img_url = $row['product_img_url'];
    $target_dir = "../assets/img/temp_img/";
    $img_link = $target_dir.$product_img_url;

    echo '<br>Add it<br><input type="checkbox" name="pic_tobe_add" value="'.$img_link.'"><br><img src="'.$img_link.'" class="img-rounded" alt="Uploaded image" width="152" height="118"><br><br>';
}
if(isset($_POST['submit_p'])) {
   if (empty($_POST['pic_tobe_add'])) {
      echo "Error: select a pic";
  }else{echo $pic_tobe_add = $_POST['pic_tobe_add'];}
}
echo '<br><input type="submit" name="submit_p" value="Add this product"><form>';
```

Comment: Since `name`of each check -box is same that's why you get only single value.`change name="pic_tobe_add"  to name="pic_tobe_add[]" ` now you will get all values. On the next page confirm it by printing out POST value using  `echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually  `name` of each `check-box` is same that's why you get only single value which is last-one.

change `name="pic_tobe_add"` to `name="pic_tobe_add[]"` (Make it array type so that you will get all the value)

On the next page confirm it by printing out POST value using `echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST);`

Comment: how can i receive all of these values in $_POST then?

Comment: I already told you. Also you have `</form>`. but i didn't see any form open code. that's strange

Comment: yes. i have open form too above that code but i didnt post here to make it small and easy to understand. since my above codes are long about 100+ lines

Comment: your form have `action = 'somepage.php'` ? on that `action page` you have to recieve all the value . so on that page write  `echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST);` and check did you get all the values of check-boxes or not?

Answer (score 1):

use `<input type="checkbox" name="pic_tobe_add[]" value="'.$img_link.'">`

```
$q2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT product_img_url FROM temp_img");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q2)) {
    $product_img_url = $row['product_img_url'];
    $target_dir = "../assets/img/temp_img/";
    $img_link = $target_dir.$product_img_url;

    echo '<br>Add it<br><input type="checkbox" name="pic_tobe_add[]" value="'.$img_link.'"><br><img src="'.$img_link.'" class="img-rounded" alt="Uploaded image" width="152" height="118"><br><br>';

}
//
    if(isset($_POST['submit_p'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['pic_tobe_add'])) {
            echo "Error: select a pic";
        }else{echo $pic_tobe_add = $_POST['pic_tobe_add'];}

}

echo '<br><input type="submit" name="submit_p" value="Add this product"><form>';
```

Comment: Why your answer is useful and why OP should have to try that. please add some description. thanks

Comment: yes i have add name="pic_tobe_add[]" instate of name="pic_tobe_add" but problem now how can i receive it from $_POST? I need all of these results in variable.

Comment: $pic_tobe_add_arr=$_POST['pic_tobe_add']; here $pic_tobe_add_arr contains all selected pic_tobe_add values or use directly foreach($_POST['pic_tobe_add'] as $item){}